# Redirect all but 2 links to new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I have `domain.de` and `domain.com`. In the past I have used both domains, but now I want to use only the domain.de and domain.com should redirect to `domain.de/en`. But there are 2 links which need to be `domain.de/api/xx1` + `domain.de/api/xx2` (so without the /en). I tried the following:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'domain.com'">
  Redirect /api/xx1 http://domain.de/api/xx1
  Redirect /api/xx2 http://domain.de/api/xx2
  Redirect / http://www.domain.de/en
</If>
```

But it only redirects everything to `.de/en` and ignores the two links, how would I change it so that it works?

Comment: Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`.

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed that it doesn't work like that since the api call cant follow redirects. Now I want to exclude the /api sub-directory from the redirect. So that everything from domain.com except domain.com/api redirects to domain.de/en. How would this work? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `RedirectMatch` would be something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/((?!api).*)" http://www.domain.de/en/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, it still redirects /api though. Do you have any idea how to get everything apart from /api working? Thanks!!